# How to stop the entity or controller creation process in the Terminal? (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, controller, entity, keyboard-shortcuts, exit

I'm new to Symfony. I would like to know if there is a way (shortcut or anything) to stop the creation process of an entity or controller in the terminal (?). For example, if I make a typo naming the class or a property, I have to continue with the process and then, after I have created the entity, I proceed to delete all the files related to this.

I just want know if there is a simpler and faster way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: press control-c ?

Comment: It is a good question but, sadly, I don't think there is a better answer.  As soon as you enter the controller/entity name then the class is actually generated.  As soon as you finish a property the entity is updated.  I suppose you could break out after entering the property but that is probably not much help.  Maybe you could write a RemoverBundle and submit it.

Comment: @craigh neither control-c nor control-z works here.